# Why doesn't below code work with (null,null)?

Tags: c#

I know that Click event accepts a delegate that get two parameters types as Object and EventArgs and  below code works with any the given argument but why doesn't below code work with (null,null)? It just prints out a string. It shouldn't matter that I gave null `Object` and null `EventArgs`.(It works with (foo,bar) or (m,n) e.g)

**Note**: CS1026, CS1002, CS1513 errors are thrown in comma.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Hello_World
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.messageButton.Click += (null, null) => MessageBox.Show("Hello");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I corrected code.

Comment: Clearly you are not yet comfortable with lambda expression syntax.  Something you can easily work on by yourself.  I'll mention the anonymous method syntax, easier on the eyes: this.messageButton.Click += delegate { /* etc */ };

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(null, null) =>` is a lambda expression. You are now using the reserved keyword `null` as name for your method parameters. That is not allowed.

You should give the parameters real names, or discard them using `_`:

```
this.messageButton.Click += (_, __) => MessageBox.Show("Hello");
```

Comment: Ahh okay. As you see the code does not do anything with the arguments given. Just prints a message. So is there a way that I can give null object reference as parameter instead of real name? (I understand that null is reserved so I cant use it.)

Comment: You are talking about *values* for the parameters given, I talk about the parameter *names*. Something goes wrong in your understanding of this expression.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is equivalent to the method declaration.

Doing

```
this.messageButton.Click += (foo, bar) => MessageBox.Show("Hello");
```

is equivalent to this

```
this.messageButton.Click += ClickHandler;

public static void ClickHandler(object null, EventArgs null)
{
}
```

And you can't use `null` as parameters names.